# Independent docks across displays

Tags: dock

Is there a way to break out or have independent docks across displays?

I have a MacBook Pro (circa 2009, 10.6.8), which is connected to a Dell UltraSharp display, and I keep going to the bottom of the Dell display to invoke the dock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two docks (I wish you could!), but you can have a different dock for each space using [DockSpaces.](http://nscoding.co.uk/) You can also go to System Preferences>Displays>Arrangement> and drag the menu bar from one screen to the other to move the dock.

Comment: I too wish the same. Thanks for the suggestion on moving the menu, I tried it but was a bit awkward ... I submitted a feature request here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: @KM01 Awesome! I am going to do that too.

Answer (score 3):

maybe Dock Spaces? http://nscoding.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't have two Docks, but you can move it onto the Dell if that makes your life easier. If you go into Displays in Sys Prefs you can click the menu bar and drag it across, that should move the Dock with it.