# Isolate OSX Dock per Space

Tags: dock

How can I make it so that each space has its own isolated dock?

Basically what I'm looking for is:

- The dock in one space should not show the icon of an app that was open in another space.
- If I have the same program open in two different spaces, clicking on the icon in one space should not go to the app in the other space.

Is this possible natively, or with a third party program?

Comment: Considering how the Dock works, I don't see any way this is possible… I might just be missing something though.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Independent docks across displays](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24492/independent-docks-across-displays) thread, you can't do it with the native Dock system.  You will need a third party utility like [DockSpaces](http://nscoding.co.uk/).